# Siri Intent with CoreData

Tags: swift, core-data, siri

I am building a small app to play the license plate road trip game. I added a siri intent to my application that simply allows a user to say "I saw [insert state name here] license plate." I want to hook this up with my CoreData `StatePlate` object and register the license plate that the user has just seen as to true for `hasBeenSeen`.

How can I combine CoreData and Siri Intents to recognize when a user says a valid state name and then changing the value of 'hasBeenSeen' to true?

`PlateInfoIntentHandler`:

```
class PlateInfoIntentHandler: NSObject, PlateInfoIntentHandling {
    
    func handle(intent: PlateInfoIntent, completion: @escaping (PlateInfoIntentResponse) -> Void) {
        print(intent.stateName!)

        completion(PlateInfoIntentResponse.success(result: "Couldn't find it"))
    }
    
    func resolveStateName(for intent: PlateInfoIntent, with completion: @escaping (INStringResolutionResult) -> Void) {
        if intent.stateName == "stateName" {
            completion(INStringResolutionResult.needsValue())
        }else{
            completion(INStringResolutionResult.success(with: intent.stateName ?? ""))
        }
    }

}
```

`StatePlate`:

```
public class StatePlate: NSManagedObject, Identifiable {
    
    // MARK: Properties
    
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID?
    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var hasBeenSeen: NSNumber?
    
    public var seen: Bool {
        get { return Bool(exactly: hasBeenSeen ?? false) ?? false }
        set {
            hasBeenSeen = NSNumber(value: newValue)
            
            do {
                try managedObjectContext?.save()                
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: Public Functions
    
    public static func getAllPlates() -> NSFetchRequest<StatePlate> {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<StatePlate> = StatePlate.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<StatePlate>
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
        request.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        return request
    }

}
```

Comment: You can achieve this by using [App Groups](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_security_application-groups)

Comment: Thank you that worked. I also found this post helpful to solve my problem: https://medium.com/@maximbilan/ios-shared-coredata-storage-for-app-groups-447b4ba43eec